# How to show branch coverage in spring boot using Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, unit-testing, code-coverage, junit5

I run `mvn clean install` in order to show the coverage, but it only shows code coverage. I would like to know how to check branch coverage.

Code Coverage example

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use jacoco code coverage tool. It's a very good tool for Java code coverage. There is a plugin for eclipse which you can install it from:https://www.eclemma.org/installation.html

[image: jacoco coverage report]

This not only gives you the above report but also if you click on the packages/classes in this report, it will also open the file and show you in green, where all code is covered and shows in red, the code which is not covered as part of a unit test.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks denzal,

I installed jacoco. After running mvn clean install, we go to [maven_project]/target/site/jacoco-ut, then open index.html on a browser like chrome, and we can see the report.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VY6BM.png)